# Feature toggle in spring context

Tags: java, spring, featuretoggle

I want to use the feature-toggle paradigm. Specifically, I want my Spring contexts to contain different bean definitions based on a toggle.

I've come across this: http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/04/conditionally-defining-spring-beans.html, which looks ok, but maybe a bit too cumbersome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) - in short, you run your application with a profile setting, and the context contains different beans depending on that profile.

Comment: I think this is not a full solution. Unless I am reading things incorrectly, you can't mix multiple profiles. But you would want to mix multiple features in a feature-toggle solution. Right?

Comment: EDIT: Seems Spring will let you set multiple profiles, but I still suspect having features == beans is not always going to be the right granularity, but its a start.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're actually looking for is a way for Spring to manage different configuration profiles.

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, such a feature does not exist. As far as I know, people usually devise various schemes to get around that, but essentially use Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to "inject" different runtime configurations into their property files by placing `${placeholder}` into their Spring import statements and then dereferencing this placeholder as their enviroment changes (e.g. "DEV", "TEST", "PROD").

That will be changed by Spring 3.1, though - as it will introduce `@Profile` annotation which seems well coupled with Spring Java Configuration option, giving one a way to completely abandon XML configuration (should one choose to, of course).

Perhaps this article will shed more light into this: [Spring 3.1 M1: Introducing @Profile](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)